# NULL JSON Model passed to webservice when specific number of special characters

Tags: java, c#, android, json, web-services

This is driving me mad - I have an object model in android that is turned into a JSON string using GsonBuilder:

```
WorkItemModel model = new WorkItemModel();
model.Jobs = jobList;
model.Items = itemList;
model.Images = imageList;
model.Questions = questionList;
String gsonJson = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(model);
```

The string is passed to a c# webservice using this method :

```
private String callWebService(String JSONModel, URL url, int appId) throws Exception {

int connTimeout = 5000;

System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
HttpURLConnection conn = null;
try {
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    //Populate Header
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(connTimeout);
    conn.setReadTimeout(connTimeout);
    if (JSONModel != null) {
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(JSONModel.length()));
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        OutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        stream.write(JSONModel.getBytes());
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();
    } else {
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
    }

    conn.connect();

    BufferedReader inputStreamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder returnStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String streamString;
    while ((streamString = inputStreamReader.readLine()) != null) {
        returnStringBuilder.append(streamString);
    }
    inputStreamReader.close();
    return returnStringBuilder.toString();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    throw e;
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    throw e;
} catch (SSLHandshakeException e) {
    throw e;
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw e;
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
} finally {
    conn.disconnect();
}
return null;
}
```

The webservice should receive this model and then go away and do some back-end DB stuff - and for the most part, we don't have a problem, but we've had a few bug reports which I can replicate but can't seem to fix.

In the "Jobs" list in our model, we have a string property called completeNotes.  When completeNotes is filled in with 4 "£" symbols, everything still works, but when there are 5 "£" symbols, the webservice Model it receives is NULL and I can see an exception has been thrown on the webservice :

```
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Additional information: Invalid character after parsing property name. Expected ':' but got:  . Path 'Jobs', line 1, position 1585.
```

Just as a side note, this also happens with € symbols, except it only allows 2 € symbols.. on the third one it does the same thing - passes a NULL model through - the symbols don't have to be contiguous either

I won't show the whole JSON as its quite lengthy.. but the property I speak of is set like this in it :

```
"completeNotes":"£££££"
```

Has anyone got any ideas as to why this is happening - I've tried messing around with the encoding (setting it to UTF-8) but this doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding "Charset=UTF-8' to the content type header?

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; Charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: Yes.. I also forced the outputstream to write in UTF-8 too.

    stream.write(JSONModel.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

It made no difference - if the charset was to blame, I'd of thought it wouldn't accept one "£" symbol - but it accepts four.. just not five!